# Validate input 16-digit credit card number

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to validate an input string that should contain exactly 16 integer digits, no more, no less. How can I do it?

Comment: You should not do this. Lots of perfectly valid credit cards do not have 16 digits. Use the Luhn check instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check length using [len](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#len). Use [str.isdigit](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes#str.isdigit) to check the string contain only digits.

```
>>> valid = '1234567890123456'
>>> invalid = '1848934798237489324324'
>>> len(valid) == 16 and valid.isdigit()
True
>>> len(invalid) == 16 and invalid.isdigit()
False
```